# JQuery. Check value of select box and textbox with same class, Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several select boxes and textboxes with the same class and I have the following statement.
**UPDATED**

```
//This goes through each visible tr of the table with class notEmptyTable
$('.notEmptyTable tr:visible').each(function(index) {

    //This checks that the elements with class checkTextBox1IsNotEmpty its not Empty.
    if ($('.checkTextBox1IsNotEmpty ').val() != "") {
        if ($('.selTxtClass:visible').val() == "") {
            $('.selTxtClass:visible').focus();
        }
    }    
});
```

**UPDATE HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtBoxa1" class="checkTextBox1IsNotEmpty"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtBoxb1" /></td>
      <td><select id="selc1" class="selTxtClass" onchange="javascript:if (this.value = "other")txtBoxd1.style.display = 'block'"/>
          <input id="txtBoxd1" style="display:none;" class="selTxtClass"/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtBoxa1" class="checkTextBox1IsNotEmpty"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtBoxb1" /></td>
      <td><select id="selc1" class="selTxtClass" onchange="javascript:if (this.value = "other")txtBoxd1.style.display = 'block'"/>
        <input id="txtBoxd1" style="display:none;" class="selTxtClass"/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtBoxa1" class="checkTextBox1IsNotEmpty"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtBoxb1" /></td>
      <td><select id="selc1" class="selTxtClass" onchange="javascript:if (this.value = "other")txtBoxd1.style.display = 'block'"/>
        <input id="txtBoxd1" style="display:none;" class="selTxtClass"/>
      </td>
    </tr>

 </table>
```

If I do an alert with ($('.selTxtClass:visible').val()) it comes as undefined.

I want to check that the value of these elements are empty, but I cant see what is wrong with this if statement, could you give me a hand, please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to post the markup as well :)

Comment: @ Nick Craver: give me a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is part of a larger loop, currently though you're checking **all** elements with those classes, not the ones just in that row, adjust it giving the [`$()` consutrctor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) a context , the row in this case, like this:

```
$('.notEmptyTable tr:visible').each(function(index) {
    //Other loop stuff
    if ($('.checkTextBox1IsNotEmpty', this).val() != "") {
        if ($('.selTxtClass:visible', this).val() == "") {
            $('.selTxtClass:visible', this).focus();
        }
    }    
});
```

This checks the `class="checkTextBox1IsNotEmpty"` for **the current row**, which I believe is what you're after...if not just ignore this useless answer :)  Also, not *directly* related to the question, but don't use the same ID multiple times, what you have in invalid HTML and may lead to many other side-effects.

Comment: we are both forgot the "return false;" when the element is found. to brake the "each" loop when the searched element is found.

Comment: @Maksim - I agree that's normally what you'd want, but I'm not sure what's going on in the larger loop here, time for Cesar input :)

Comment: i agree,in this case its not a big problem, but this is just a good practice. it's not difficulty and it add's the only line to code.

Comment: Thank a lot, (,this) its what I was missing, and I did not know how to use it in this case.Once again Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Cesar Lopez : try to use firebug or opera dragonfly or  chrome "inspect element" feature. it saves your time when you are debugging javascript code.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
$('.selTxtClass:visible').each( function(i,e){
    if(e.val()==''){
        e.focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: No need for a `.html()` check on input elements, remove that and it's +1 for correctness from me :)

Comment: Thanks for your very quick replay, I am going to try your solution, but I was wondering if it was a way to avoid .each(), as it is already inside of another .each(). Thanks.